# Javascript function call not working within gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Now this WAS working, I dont know what 
I've changed but can anyone see why the call is not working
im getting getSetContactID is not defined from the browser

Here is the markup from the webform including the script

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quick Donate">
   <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Button ID="btnQuickDonate" CssClass="btn-sm btn-primary" runat="server"
              CommandName="Insert" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
              OnClientClick='<%# "getSetContactID(\"" + Container.DataItemIndex + "\")" %>'
             OnClick="btnQuickDonate_Click" Text="Quick &#010;Donate" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
  //functions returns the dataitemindex (row Number) from the btnQuickDonate (which is the contactID)
  function getSetContactID(rowIndex, obj) {
     var CellValue, cell, dataItemIndex;

     var table = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID %>');

     cell = table.rows[parseInt(rowIndex) + 1].cells[1];

     //cell = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').rows[parseInt(t) + 1].cells[1];

     dataItemIndex = cell.innerHTML;  //this will get items inside cell (Not needed because the ContactID is hidden so using the row index in row behind with dataitemindex)

    //alert(dataItemIndex + "row index" + rowIndex);

          $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "WebService1.asmx/setContactIDGV1",    
                 data: '{DataItemIndex: "' + rowIndex + '"}',
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: "done",  //after contactID taken click btnQuickDonate to set donation amount
                 failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                          }
                  })
     }
   </script>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your JS out of ItemTemplate. Worth a try.

Comment: Looks like worked  - although it has been working with the script inside = thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing second Argument in function calling

```
OnClientClick='<%# "getSetContactID(\"" + Container.DataItemIndex + "\")" %>'



function getSetContactID(rowIndex, obj) {
```

Comment: Ive removed the second parameter as I dont think I'm using it function getSetContactID(rowIndex) but still getting the same error